# No Sound In Headphones Dell studio 17

Tags: sound, headphones

I recently decided to try Ubuntu. I made a dual-boot installation on my Dell Studio 17.

The audio plays just fine through the speakers, but will not play through the headphones. Only one of the head phone jacks is acknowledged as an output source.

Please help. I am new to Ubuntu so step by step instructions would be preferable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, turned out the second headphone jacked was muted. This can be seen when you start `alsamixer` in the terminal.

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select playback items and <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to select the second headphone. Mute/unmute with <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: In alsamixer it says the headphones are turned up to 100% volume and I still do not get any sound out of them.